# Infos: Ereur : com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectTextPacket cannot be cast to javax.jms.StreamMessage

Tags: java, ms-access, ejb, jms

I am trying to get a message sent by a JMSProducer through the Message driven bean above, and I get a cast error in my glassfish 4.1 server log.
Any help please.

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/TestDestination")
,@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")})
public class PhotoReceiverMB implements MessageListener{
public void onMessage(Message arg) {
     try {
         StreamMessage message = (StreamMessage)arg ;
     }
     catch(Exception e){}
  }
}
```

This is the message producer :

```
public class JMSSender {
   public static String send(String nomPhoto) throws NamingException, JMSException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory factory= (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("jms/TestConnectionFactory");
        Destination destination = (Destination)ctx.lookup("jms/TestDestination");
        try (Connection connexion = factory.createConnection()) {
            Session session = 
            connexion.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer=session.createProducer(destination);
            File f = new File("photos/"+photoName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            byte[] data = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            fis.read(data);
            StreamMessage message = session.createStreamMessage();
            message.setStringProperty("photoName", photoName);
            message.setIntProperty("size",data.length );
            message.writeBytes(data);
            producer.send(message);
        }
        return "Ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: As the message says: cannot cast to StreamMessage. Check the message type sent by the producer. Did you import javax.jms.StreamMessage both places? (NetBeans find three types with the same name with JEE 7)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.As you can see the type sent by the producer is actually a streamMessage, what do you suggest to do in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The `com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectTextPacket` message implements the `javax.jms.TextMessage` and not `javax.jms.StreamMessage` interface. So they are not compatible types. There are two solutions:

- The sender should producer `javax.jms.StreamMessage`messages.
- The MDB should consume  `javax.jms.TextMessage` messages.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but as you see the sender is actually producing a streamMessage and both StreamMessage and TextMessage interfaces extends Message interface. so basicly : a reference of Message should be able to be down casted to StreamMessage reference! do you agree with me?

Comment: if you don't want to use nothing special from xxxMessage, then yes. but in this case the sender and the receiver can use this type as well (no need for special contents).

Comment: Actually I need to send a picture with jms from a swing client to a jee application

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to use message.getText() and do not call the output on Message.